# Select other li in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When put my mouse on a li element, I want the change the opacity of the other li from the ul. Is that possible just with CSS (I'm using SASS) ? If I'm not on a li, all the li are opacity:1.

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>  //opacity 0.5
    <li></li>  //opacity 0.5
    <li></li>  <= hover on this li //opacity 1
    <li></li>  //opacity 0.5
    <li></li>  //opacity 0.5
    <li></li>  //opacity 0.5
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to change the opacity of all items to 0.5 on `ul:hover` and  opacity 1 on `li:hover`. The latter is more specific so it applies before the more general one.

```css
ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> opacity 0.5 </li>
    <li> opacity 0.5 </li>
    <li> hover on this li //opacity 1 </li>
    <li> opacity 0.5 </li>
    <li> opacity 0.5 </li>
    <li> opacity 0.5 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The latter takes precedence by virtue of being the latter alone. The specificity is equal. Note also that this only works if you don't care that all of the items will be semitransparent for as long as the pointer is anywhere on the ul - for example if there are margins between items.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* The opacity when hovered. */
ul li {opacity: 1}

/* The opacity when the li is not hovered */
ul li:not(:hover) {opacity:0.5}
```

Comment: Default state is also an unhovered state. So this will always show `opacity: 0.5` when there is no hover on any `li` element.

Answer (score 1):

This simple trick should do it:

```css
ul:hover > li{
  opacity: .5;
}

ul:hover > li:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1111</li> 
    <li>2222</li> 
    <li>3333</li> 
    <li>4444</li> 
    <li>5555</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are using sass, you can use specific syntax who will be interpreted when you create your generated css

```
ul 
{
&:hover
    {         
    li  {
        opacity: 1;             
        }
    }
li 
    {
    &:hover
        {
        opacity:0.5;
        }
     }
  }
```

once generated will become

```
 ul:hover li {opacity: 0.5;}
 ul li:hover {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: User is looking for the reverse and also have default opacity as 1.

Comment: But now the default opacity is 0.5 which is not what is indicated in question. Default should be 1 and when an element is hovered on, all elements except the hovered one should be 0.5